# Codeigniter form URI loses segment when failing validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using codeigniter 2.1.2, I have a form view loaded through a controller that takes a parameter. This parameter is a boolean that tells the view whether to render certain content on the form.

the URI of the standard form is: `ordering/create/`
but if the form should be rendering as a 'holiday' form is: `ordering/create/holiday`

If the submitted form does not pass validation, the standard form is always shown. How do I get the last segment to persist through validation and form re-population?

Here is my controller function.

```
public function create($holiday = NULL)
{
    $data['holiday'] = ($holiday != NULL) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    //load the code igniter helpers we'll be using
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //set the page title
    $data['title'] = 'Create an Order';

    //validate the form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstName','First Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastName','Last Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phoneNumber','Phone Number','required|callback_validate_phoneNumber');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailAddress','Email Address','required|valid_email');               
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pickupDate','Pickup Date','required|callback_validate_pickupDate');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pickupTime','Pickup Time','required');

    //check that at least one product was selected
    $this->load->model('products_model');
    $data['products'] = $this->products_model->get_online_products($data['holiday']);
    $productSelections = array();
    $totalProducts = 0;
    foreach($data['products']->result() as $product)
    {
        $productSelections[$product->productProductSizeId] = $this->input->post('product_'.$product->productProductSizeId);
        $totalProducts += $productSelections[$product->productProductSizeId];
    }

    $pickupDate = new DateTime($this->input->post('pickupDate'));

    //if the form failed validation, or there is no form data yet, send the user back to the form
    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE || $totalProducts == 0)
    {
        $this->load->model('calendar_model');
        $data['calendarRules'] = $this->calendar_model->get_rules($data['holiday']);

        $data['productSelections'] = $productSelections;

        if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE && $totalProducts == 0)
        {
            $data['productsError'] = 'You must order at least one product';
        }

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('ordering/create', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        //save the data to the DB
        $savedData = $this->ordering_model->create_order($data['holiday']);

        //send the confirmation email and redirect to the confirmation page
        $this->send_confirmation($savedData['orderHeader']['orderId']);
    }
}
```

Comment: using form_validation->set_rules. I added code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller `ordering`, create a method `create($holiday = null)`.

Then you do this:

```
$data['holiday'] = ($holiday != NULL) ? true : false;
$this->load->view('yourView', $data);
```

To persist the value of `holiday` you should set the form submit action accordingly.

In your view, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$submitUrl = site_url('ordering/create');
if ($holiday) {
    $submitUrl .= '/holiday';
}

<form method="post" action="<?= $submitUrl ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing. I added code to the question. See anything else?